# Reducing repetition and utlizing EDT

Tags: java, swing, gui

I am working on the largest Java program I have undertaken to date and feel uncertain in my current code practices. I think that I state and repeat things that don't need to be which can become a headache as development goes on. Specifically, in my GridBag Constraints. I have worked with GridBagLayout before and had gotten what I needed without declaring the width and height of cells that are only (1,1), yet here I was having problems so I decided to define everything I could think of for every cell and I got what I wanted, but now I probably have unnecessary code.

My other concern is in regards to utilizing the EDT. I've done my best to find lessons and videos on the subject but still feel that I have a lack of sufficient understanding.

**FrontierMain.java:**

```
public class FrontierMain  {

    public FrontierMain(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Frontier Insulation Labor Record Tool");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        LaborRecordPanel recordPanel = new LaborRecordPanel();
        frame.add(recordPanel.scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                FrontierMain fm = new FrontierMain();   
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

**LaborRecordPanel.java:**

```
public class LaborRecordPanel implements
Printable, ActionListener {

    private Color shade = new Color(201,201,201); // color for shaded cells

    private JLabel dateSpace[] = new JLabel[7]; 
    private JLabel grandTotalSpace = new JLabel();
    private JLabel locAndDescSpace = new JLabel();
    private JLabel personnelSpace[] = new JLabel[10]; //  empty cells
    private JLabel calendarGridLines[] = new JLabel[300]; //empty labels for gridlines

    private ImageIcon logoIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/fici_logo1.jpg");
    private JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(logoIcon);

    private JLabel authorizedBy = new JLabel("AUTHORIZED BY:_____________________________________________________________");
    private JLabel toCertify = new JLabel("THIS IS TO CERTIFY THAT THE ABOVE LABOR HAS BEEN PERFORMED.");

    private JLabel laborRecordNO = new JLabel("NO.");
    private JLabel nameOfJob = new JLabel("NAME OF JOB:");
    private JLabel customerPO = new JLabel("CUSTOMER PO #:");
    private JLabel contractNO = new JLabel("CONTRACT NO.");
    private JLabel weekEnding = new JLabel("WEEK ENDING");

    private JLabel personnelList = new JLabel("<html>LIST SUPERVISION &<br> CRAFT LABOR BELOW:</html>");
    private JLabel locAndDescriptionLabel = new JLabel("LOCATION AND DESCRIPTION:");

    private JLabel personnelTitle = new JLabel("TITLE");

    private JLabel[] titleSpace= new JLabel[10];

    private JLabel calendarTitle = new JLabel("NUMBER OF HOURS WORKED @ SITE");
    private JLabel dayHeading = new JLabel("DAY");
    private JLabel dateHeading = new JLabel("DATE");
    private JLabel[] ot2 = new JLabel[10];
    private JLabel[] ot1 = new JLabel[10];
    private JLabel[] st = new JLabel[10];

    private JLabel mon = new JLabel("MON");
    private JLabel tues = new JLabel("TUES");
    private JLabel wed = new JLabel("WED");
    private JLabel thur = new JLabel("THUR");
    private JLabel fri = new JLabel("FRI");
    private JLabel sat = new JLabel("SAT");
    private JLabel sun = new JLabel("SUN");

    private JLabel totalHours = new JLabel("<html>TOTAL<br> HOURS</html>");
    private JLabel ratePerHour = new JLabel("<html>RATE<br> PER<br> HOUR</html>");
    private JLabel totalAmount = new JLabel("<html>TOTAL<br> AMOUNT</html>");
    private JLabel grandTotal = new JLabel("TOTAL");

    JButton printTest = new JButton("PrintTest");

    JPanel rp = new JPanel();
    JPanel outer = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outer);

    LaborRecordPanel(){

        outer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(outer,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ));
        outer.add(rp);
        outer.add(buttonPanel);
        printTest.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(printTest);
        rp.setBorder(null);
        rp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1295,1830 ));
        rp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1295,1830 ));
        rp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1295,1830 ));

        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1295,800 ));

        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50); //increase the scroll speed

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) titleSpace[i] = new JLabel(); // create mechanic labels

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) //create labels for work time
        {
            ot2[i] = new JLabel("OT-2");
            ot1[i] = new JLabel("OT-1");
            st[i] = new JLabel("S.T.");
        }
        //create empty labels for gridlines
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) personnelSpace[i] = new JLabel(); 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) dateSpace[i] = new JLabel();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 299; i++) calendarGridLines[i] = new JLabel();

        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        rp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        rp.setLayout(gridbag);

        //row 0////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 10;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        laborRecordNO.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        laborRecordNO.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        gridbag.setConstraints(laborRecordNO, gbc);
        rp.add(laborRecordNO, gbc);

        //row 1////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 13;
        gridbag.setConstraints(logoLabel, gbc);
        rp.add(logoLabel, gbc);

        //row 2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        nameOfJob.setFont(nameOfJob.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(nameOfJob, gbc);
        rp.add(nameOfJob, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 10;
        contractNO.setFont(contractNO.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(contractNO, gbc);
        rp.add(contractNO, gbc);

        //row 3////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        customerPO.setFont(customerPO.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(customerPO, gbc);
        rp.add(customerPO, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 10;
        weekEnding.setFont(weekEnding.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(weekEnding, gbc);
        rp.add(weekEnding, gbc);

        //row 4////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .01;
        personnelList.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        personnelList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        personnelList.setFont(personnelList.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(personnelList, gbc);
        rp.add(personnelList, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .42;
        personnelTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        personnelTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        personnelTitle.setFont(personnelTitle.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(personnelTitle, gbc);
        rp.add(personnelTitle, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 8;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .5;
        calendarTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        calendarTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        calendarTitle.setFont(calendarTitle.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(calendarTitle, gbc);
        rp.add(calendarTitle, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 10;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .05;
        totalHours.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        totalHours.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        totalHours.setFont(totalHours.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(totalHours, gbc);
        rp.add(totalHours, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 11;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        ratePerHour.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        ratePerHour.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        ratePerHour.setFont(ratePerHour.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(ratePerHour, gbc);
        rp.add(ratePerHour, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 12;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        totalAmount.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        totalAmount.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        totalAmount.setFont(totalAmount.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(totalAmount, gbc);
        rp.add(totalAmount, gbc);

        //row 5//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        dayHeading.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        dayHeading.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        dayHeading.setFont(dayHeading.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(dayHeading, gbc);
        rp.add(dayHeading, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        mon.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        mon.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        mon.setFont(mon.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(mon, gbc);
        rp.add(mon, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        tues.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        tues.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        tues.setFont(tues.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(tues, gbc);
        rp.add(tues, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        wed.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        wed.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        wed.setFont(wed.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(wed, gbc);
        rp.add(wed, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        thur.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        thur.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        thur.setFont(thur.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(thur, gbc);
        rp.add(thur, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 7;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .09;
        fri.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        fri.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        fri.setFont(fri.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(fri, gbc);
        rp.add(fri, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 8;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        sat.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        sat.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        sat.setFont(sat.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(sat, gbc);
        rp.add(sat, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 9;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = .07;
        sun.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        sun.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        sun.setFont(sun.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(sun, gbc);
        rp.add(sun, gbc);

        //row 6//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 6;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        dateHeading.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        dateHeading.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        dateHeading.setFont(dateHeading.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(dateHeading, gbc);
        rp.add(dateHeading, gbc);   

        int dateSpaceIndex = 3;
        boolean flip = true;
        for (int k = 0; k <= 6; k++)//create gridlines for day area
        {
            gbc.gridx = dateSpaceIndex;
            gbc.gridy = 6;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            if(flip) dateSpace[k].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
            else dateSpace[k].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            gridbag.setConstraints(dateSpace[k], gbc);
            rp.add(dateSpace[k], gbc);
            dateSpaceIndex++;
            flip = !flip;
        }



        //row 13-36 plus 7-12 time worked labels//////////////////////////
        for (int r = 0; r <= 9; r++)
        {
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 7 + (3*r);
            gbc.gridheight = 3;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            titleSpace[r].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            titleSpace[r].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
            titleSpace[r].setFont(titleSpace[r].getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
            gridbag.setConstraints(titleSpace[r], gbc);
            rp.add(titleSpace[r], gbc);
        }

        for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++){
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 7 + (3*c);
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            ot2[c].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            ot2[c].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            ot2[c].setFont(ot2[c].getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
            gridbag.setConstraints(ot2[c], gbc);
            rp.add(ot2[c], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 8 + (3*c);
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            ot1[c].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            ot1[c].setOpaque(true);
            ot1[c].setBackground(shade);
            ot1[c].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            ot1[c].setFont(ot1[c].getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
            gridbag.setConstraints(ot1[c], gbc);
            rp.add(ot1[c], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 9 + (3*c);
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            st[c].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            st[c].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            st[c].setFont(st[c].getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
            gridbag.setConstraints(st[c], gbc);
            rp.add(st[c], gbc);
        }
        //row 37/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 37;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        locAndDescriptionLabel.setFont(locAndDescriptionLabel.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(locAndDescriptionLabel, gbc);
        rp.add(locAndDescriptionLabel);

        gbc.gridx = 11;
        gbc.gridy = 37;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        grandTotal.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        grandTotal.setOpaque(true);
        grandTotal.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        grandTotal.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        grandTotal.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
        grandTotal.setFont(grandTotal.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(grandTotal, gbc);
        rp.add(grandTotal);

        gbc.gridx = 12;
        gbc.gridy = 37;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        grandTotalSpace.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
        gridbag.setConstraints(grandTotalSpace, gbc);
        rp.add(grandTotalSpace);

        //row 38////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 38;
        gbc.gridwidth = 10;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.ipady = 80;
        locAndDescSpace.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
        gridbag.setConstraints(locAndDescSpace, gbc);
        rp.add(locAndDescSpace);

        //row 39////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.ipady = 0; //reset to default
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 39;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 13;
        toCertify.setFont(toCertify.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(toCertify, gbc);
        rp.add(toCertify);

        //row 40///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 40;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 13;
        authorizedBy.setFont(authorizedBy.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        gridbag.setConstraints(authorizedBy, gbc);
        rp.add(authorizedBy);


        for (int r = 0; r <= 9; r++)//gridlines for personnel space
        {
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 7 + (3*r);
            gbc.gridheight = 3;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            personnelSpace[r].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            gridbag.setConstraints(personnelSpace[r], gbc);
            rp.add(personnelSpace[r]);
        }
        //create calendar grid lines
        int yPointer = 7;
        int xPointer = 3;
        int shadePtr = 8;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 299; j++)
        {
            gbc.gridx = xPointer;
            gbc.gridy = yPointer;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            calendarGridLines[j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
            if (yPointer == shadePtr){ //if row number = shadePtr then color the cell
                calendarGridLines[j].setOpaque(true);
                calendarGridLines[j].setBackground(shade);
            }
            gridbag.setConstraints(calendarGridLines[j], gbc);
            rp.add(calendarGridLines[j]);
            xPointer++; //go to next cell in row
            j++; //use the next jlabel
            gbc.gridx = xPointer;
            gbc.gridy = yPointer;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            calendarGridLines[j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            if (yPointer == shadePtr){ //if row number = shadePtr then color the cell
                calendarGridLines[j].setOpaque(true);
                calendarGridLines[j].setBackground(shade);
            }
            gridbag.setConstraints(calendarGridLines[j], gbc);
            rp.add(calendarGridLines[j]);

            xPointer++; //go to next cell in row

            if(xPointer == 13) //if end of column then go to next row and reset column pointer to 3 and increment shade pointer by 3
            {
                yPointer++; //go down a row
                xPointer = 3;
                if((j % 3) == 0) {
                    shadePtr = yPointer;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printJob.setPrintable(this);
        if (printJob.printDialog()){
            try{
                printJob.print();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int index)
            throws PrinterException {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        if (index >= 1){
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        else {
            AffineTransform originalTransform = g2.getTransform();

            double scaleX = pf.getImageableWidth() / rp.getWidth();
            double scaleY = pf.getImageableHeight() / rp.getHeight();
            // Maintain aspect ratio
            double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            g2.scale(scale, scale);
            rp.printAll(g2);

            g2.setTransform(originalTransform);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Images of GUI may help.  Top and bottom half respectively.

[image: top]

[image: bottom]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHOD EXTRACTION**   that's the key to fixing a lot of what you do....

Consider this code:

> ```
>     //row 2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>     gbc.gridx = 0;
>     gbc.gridy = 2;
>     gbc.gridheight = 1;
>     gbc.gridwidth = 1;
>     nameOfJob.setFont(nameOfJob.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
>     gridbag.setConstraints(nameOfJob, gbc);
>     rp.add(nameOfJob, gbc);
>
>     gbc.gridx = 5;
>     gbc.gridy = 2;
>     gbc.gridheight = 1;
>     gbc.gridwidth = 10;
>     contractNO.setFont(contractNO.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
>     gridbag.setConstraints(contractNO, gbc);
>     rp.add(contractNO, gbc);
> ```

What if you had a method:

```
public static addGridComponent(JComponent container, JComponent component, 
                 GridBagLayout gridbag, GridBagConstraints gbc,
                 int x, int y, int height, int width, float font) {
    gbc.gridx = x;
    gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridheight = height;
    gbc.gridwidth = width;
    component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
    gridbag.setConstraints(component, gbc);
    container.add(component, gbc);
}
```

Then your code would become:

```
//row 2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
addGridComponent(rp, nameOfJob,  gridbag, gbc, 0, 2, 1, 1,  18.0f);
addGridComponent(rp, contractNO, gridbag, gbc, 5, 2, 1, 10, 18.0f);

//row 3////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
addGridComponent(rp, customerPO, gridbag, gbc, 0, 3, 1, 1,  18.0f);
addGridComponent(rp, weekEnding, gridbag, gbc, 5, 3, 1, 10, 18.0f)
```

This does not solve the problem with the magic numbers, but Marc-Andre has already addressed that. What it does solve is a huge amount of code repetition.

Comment: thanks @rolfl, that's very helpful. I'm in the process of refactoring my code according to your and Marc-Andre's answers.

Comment: @Marc-Andre good spotting. Thanks, Fixed

Answer (score 6):

From a quick look at your code, I can say that your constructor is too big. I would suggest to refactored your constructor into smaller functions with only one task to do. I would probably have different method for each "zone" or "group" of elements.

There is a lot of magic numbers in your code. Why 5? Why not 6 ? You could use variable with names instead of directly use the number. It would help grasp easily why you're using 5 (Maybe it's the size of a ideal row, etc). A good example of a magic number would be this code :

```
private JLabel[] ot2 = new JLabel[10];
private JLabel[] ot1 = new JLabel[10];
private JLabel[] st = new JLabel[10];
```

Why are you using 10 ? I guess is the number of columns or somethings like that. But what happens if you need to change it to 11 ? You need to replace each occurence of 10 to 11. But 10 conveys a meaning, it's the number of columns, so you could have `private final int NUMBERS_OF_COLUMNS = 10`. It would clear to anyone reading your code that you're creating an of labels for each columns.

```
if(flip) dateSpace[k].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
else dateSpace[k].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
```

It was hard at first glance to see that there was an if-else here. You should use `{}` to help see at first glance that there is an if statement. This will improve readability and will help a lot with unsuspected bugs or changing the code later on.

Use only one style of formatting. Sometimes you're using :

```
for (...)
{

}
```

And I see that you use this variant too :

```
for (...) {

}
```

Choose only one and keep it in all your code (this is something that an IDE can do automatically).

One final tips that I could give you, find relevant names for your variables. You're doing a good job for the majority of your code, but sometimes you'r using contraction that are not that helpful. For example : `JPanel rp = new JPanel();` What is an `rp` ? An other example : `GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();`. We already know that it's an grid bag by the declaration of the class. You could use something more meaningful. Is the principal container or a container for the data of the weeks or anything else? I always find more helpful to know at glance what the container is used for, just by reading his name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "magic numbers". I think it would help to show my gui, I edited my post with the top and bottom half of the gui. After seeing this, do my numbers still seem arbitrary? If so, I will take action on it.

Comment: @solleks I've made an edit to better explain my point.

Comment: ah yes, your edit helped very much. I'll be making your suggested changes. If you choose to go into deeper review, I would very much appreciate any suggestions or comments regarding the usage of EDT and `GridBagConstraints`.

Comment: For the moment I can't elaborate much, but if I can be sure that I will do it!

Answer (score 1):

1. The variable declaration is unnecessary here:

   ```
   public void run() {
       final FrontierMain fm = new FrontierMain();
   }
   ```

   The following is the same:

   ```
   public void run() {
       new FrontierMain();
   }
   ```

   (Eclipse also puts a yellow exclamation mark on the line.)
2. I think you are using EDT correctly. Just make sure that creation and every access (read or modify) to Swing components happens on EDT. Swing calls event handlers on EDT, including `actionPerformed()` and `Printable.print()`.

   If you are not sure you can always check that a method runs on EDT or not with [`SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread%28%29). You could create a custom method for that:

   ```
   public static void verifyEventDispatchThread() {
       if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
           Thread.dumpStack();
       }
   }
   ```

   but there are other, already existing solutions: [Swing verify code on event dispatch thread at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3014972/843804)